# How to log from core libraries

Tags: java, log4j

I am uisng log4j in one of my applications, the code is as follows;

```
 log=/var/lib/openshift/5372745b4382ec49cb0000d5/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossas/deployments/Logs/AppName.log
 org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
 log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE

 log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
 log4j.appender.FILE.append=true log4j.appender.FILE.file=${log}
 log4j.appender.FILE.threshold=DEBUG
 log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
 log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n
```

This application also will use some core application code which is shared between various apps - How do i therefore log from this core code base as it will be shared amongst many applications - this means i can't provide a concrete log= value

Would something like this suffice?

> log=/var/lib/openshift/5372745b4382ec49cb0000d5/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossas/deployments/Logs/*.log

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to

- have different File appenders for each appplication
- Load those appeanders in the respective Application Logger.

  protected static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(X.class);

  ```
  static
  {
      if (null == LOGGER.getAppender("TEST_LOG_APPENDER"))
      {
          RollingFileAppender fa = new RollingFileAppender();
          fa.setName("TEST_LOG_APPENDER");
          fa.setFile("/test-output/" + "App_1.log");
          fa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"));
          fa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
          fa.setAppend(true);
          fa.setMaxFileSize("10MB");
          fa.activateOptions();
          LOGGER.addAppender(fa);
      }
  }
  ```

Note that here you need not to create new appender, rather remove others and use only one.
Also this will work if you have a common app level logger.

Not sure if this is a right way of doing it. But just a thought.